# Join And Sum On Secondary Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the two following table structures:

Questions Table

```
QuestionID | Response
1              Yes
2              No
1              No
```

Question Lookup Table

```
QuestionID | Lookup
1              No
2              No
3              No
```

I am trying to get a sum of when the Lookup and Response are equal. For example, QuestionID 1 has a Lookup value of "No". In the Question table, there are two QuestionID's with the value of 1. One of those responses has a value of No, so I would increment the return by 1, and grouping the end result by the QuestionID.

Comment: The table naming is actually kind of confusing. In my understanding, Questions table is really the Response table. And the QuestionLookupTable is the real question/answer table. This seems to be a grading problem of some sort. Probably his/her homework. Please correct me if I'm incorrect. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.QuestionId, SUM(CASE WHEN(b.Lookup = a.Response) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
FROM Questions a
INNER JOIN QuestionLookup b ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId
GROUP BY a.QuestionId
```

Comment: Why do you need the case statement? Why not just do it in the WHERE clause?

Comment: You don't **need** it. Just another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need if you're only trying to see how many correct answers there were.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QuestionLookupTable Q
INNER JOIN Questions R
  ON Q.QuestionID = R.QuestionID
WHERE Q.Lookup = R.Response
```

If which question got how many correct answer is important...

```
SELECT Q.QuestionID, COUNT(*) FROM QuestionLookupTable Q
INNER JOIN Questions R
  ON Q.QuestionID = R.QuestionID
WHERE Q.Lookup = R.Response
GROUP BY Q.QuestionID
```